# Session state controller in Umbraco

Tags: model-view-controller, controller, umbraco

I have a custom controller in ~/Controllers/Api/Test.cs inherited from SurfaceController.

What will be routed URL for it ?

Answer (score 0):

All is documented here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/routing/surface-controllers. If it supposed to be an API controller, you should probably inherit from **UmbracoApiController** to be able to use standard WebAPI features with addition of Umbraco Context and Helper injected inside.

More info about it: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Routing/WebApi/

Comment: Marcin, and how exactly can I access Session via Umbraco Context ?

Comment: What exactly you want from session? This is a standard ASP.NET sessionstate which you're able to use everywhere (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx). UmbracoContext is a different object which contains many other useful informations about current umbraco state: https://our.umbraco.org/apidocs/csharp/api/Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.html.